# I updated PHP from source... How can I use it?

Tags: php, unix, update, installation

I'm on a Mac, and it has PHP 5.3.4 built in.

I downloaded the sources of PHP 5.3.6 and installed it via

```
./configure; sudo make; sudo make install
```

It is now installed in /usr/local/bin/php:

```
/usr/local/bin/php  -v
PHP 5.3.6 (cli) (built: May  9 2011 12:04:28)
```

However when I run the php command, I still get old php version:

```
php -v
PHP 5.3.4 (cli) (built: Dec 15 2010 12:15:07)
```

The location is also different:

```
which php
/usr/bin/php
```

I can run the scripts with new PHP by specifying the full path, but how can I make it like

```
php5.3.6 hello_world.php
```

?

Thank you

Comment: Have you edited your apache conf?

Comment: There is no need for `sudo` when using `make`. Only `make install` might need rootpermissions to write to protected directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably want to use the alias command.

Assuming you're using bash create a file called `~/.bash_aliases`

and add the following to it:

```
alias php5.3.6="/usr/local/bin/php"
alias php5.3.4="/usr/bin/php"
```

I'd recommend only having one version of PHP installed at a time and unless you really need to compile from source would suggest you use some kind of packaged binary install (like an RPM or .deb package)

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for... Didn't know about aliasing. I love *nix more and more with every day

Comment: if the `.bash_aliases` file isn't parsed (I don't have a mac to verify) then try adding it to `~/.bashrc`

Comment: In fact I just ran the command alias php5.3.6="/usr/local/bin/php" in terminal, and it worked! I didn't even have to edit any files.

Comment: @Alex: The issue is that `alias` doesn't persist across reboots (or indeed, even across sessions!).  If you want it to work consistently, you'll need to add it to a file somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a symlink in `/usr/bin`. Dont know mac very well. Under linux its like

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/php /usr/bin/php5.3.6
```

Should be similar under the apple.